# In Windows, what options are available to cache, index and search text files (that contain encoded images)

Tags: wpf, windows

I'm writing a grid view that will display a list of thumbnails (each representing a file). Potentially, the view could display thousands of files. The files will be text only (but will contain images that have been encoded). Basically, I want the same kind of layout that Picasa provides (with the same kind of speed/user responsiveness).

Here's some more criteria:

- The data in the file will be a complex data structure, but may not be consistent (i.e. data may exist in some files but not others)
- When retrieving data for the grid view, I'd like to be able to filter the contents and control the sort order
- I'd like to be able to index the files; to (potentially?) improve data retrieval performance
- If the data is cached, I'll need to synchronise the data somehow and detect when a change has been made
- If I end up using a third party solution:

  - I'd like to choose a technology that I could re-distribute to the end user; and
  - Is simple to install. Ideally files that can be copied to the users PC inside the application install folder

My first thoughts are that I should store the contents of the files in a database (such as Sqlite) or use an indexing service (such as Lucene). But then I know nothing about these technologies and whether there are more appropriate solutions out there.

So, suggestions anyone?